# Posting phonegap image to php/mysql - image field disappears from post request?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cordova, base64

I am retrieving an image from a user's gallery, and trying to post the base64 encoded version to a server using php and mysql. The base64 string returned is:

```
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
```

The code used to post (base64 string is cameraPic):

```
$.post("https://www.domaintopostto.co.uk/API/users.php", { user: usernamePost, userID: result.id, gender: gender, image: cameraPic }, function (data) {
console.log(data);
console.log("HERE");
if (data.result = "Added") {
    window.location = "sportsSelector.html";
}
});
```

PHP code on the server:

```
$image = $_POST['image'];
$base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $image);

$sql = "INSERT INTO userActivityLocation(user, userID, gender, image)VALUES('$user', '$userID', '$gender', '$base64img')";
```

The base64 string does not appear in the db. In fact, the `image: cameraPic` pasrt of the request entirely disappears.....it isnt there in the network view in chrome. The other fields fire off okay and show up in chrome. No errors in console, none echoed from the server.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

i tried to replicate your scripts and this is working for me :

```
var cameraPic = "yourverylongencodedstring";
$.post("query.php", { image: cameraPic }, function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   });
```

on query.php i have :

```
<?php 
 $image = $_POST['image'];
 $base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $image);
 echo $base64img;
 ?>
```

and i can see the correct response string in network panel in chrome;

so i am wondering:

-you're passing an empty cameraPic var?

-if it doesn't show up after the sql query, the sql field is large enough for the string?

-you have not whitelisted "www.domaintopostto.co.uk" ?

Trying to guess!

Comment: I've tried all the above - I think it might be the modal window interfering with the event listener id attached to a button....i'm having a play around now! Thanks for the tips